# Вывод ссылок в документе

Tags: jquery

Пытаюсь получить ссылки из меню и вывести их в блоке с классом html-map, но ссылки не выводятся, как исправить?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var html_link = [];
        if(location.pathname == '/html-karta'){
            $.each($("ul.menu-main a"), function(i,e) {
                html_link.push($(e).attr('href'));
                $.each(html_link, function(i,e){
                    $('.html-map').html($(e));  
                })
            })
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем понял ход мыслей в вашем коде )

Рабочее решение

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (location.pathname == '/html-karta'){            
        $.each($("ul.menu-main a"), function() {                
            $('.html-map').append($(this).html());  
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: а не подскажите, как к ссылке добавить href?
Просто такая конструкция не работает
 `$('.html-map').append('<a>'+$(this).attr('href').html()+'</a><br>');`

Comment: $('.html-map').append('<a href="' + $(this).attr('href') +'">Link text</a‌​><br>')

Comment: Или так
var  htmlMap =  $('.html-map');
$('a', {'href' : $(this).attr('href')}).appendTo(htmlMap);

Comment: Если меню вложенное можно ли каким нибудь образом, получить ссылки и вывести их с такой вложенностью как в меню?

Comment: Имхо, создайте еще одни вопрос. В нем сформулируйте проблему которая у Вас возникла. Только не забудьте добавить код с которым проблемы.